# Image will not display

Tags: python, html, image, flask

I am using Python / Flask and am trying to have a chart display on the webpage.  The chart created using plt.savefig('chart.png') and I can see the it in the desired folder, which is in the same folder as the python file, but when I run the program, I just a broken image logo instead of the chart on the webpage.  The index.html file is in the templates folder.

I also see this within the pycharm console
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2020 21:37:39] "GET /chart.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="chart.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem with the following code:

```py
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def index():
    return """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="chart.png">
</body>
</html>
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

And then you can open a browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/.

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```html
+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

html propare name of imagee source any name of image like jpeg.image

```html
 </head>
    <body bgcolor=" ">
   <img src="{{media_url}}{{image.image}}">
```